# AIR for Android checking internet connection issue ( actionscript 3 )

Tags: android, flash, actionscript, air

I'm developing a simple app for my school which will show you the newest updates from the website, but checking the internet connection seems a little problem in AIR.

I'll be more specific:

- I'm using Adobe Flash CS6 to develop the app (Using AIR for android)
- The app contains a menu, and the "internet frame", of which the code doesn't really work.
- I've tried a couple of things already: URLMonitor(like is available = true), URLLoader(and cathing the IOError if it occurs when there's no internet connection) and something like HTMLLoader (long time ago :P, no success)
- The URLLoader works "fine", but I also need to know if the webpage just isn't available (404) when there IS an active internet connection, but in either those cases it will just throw the same "stream error" , so I can distinguish them. That's why it doesn't suit my needs.
- The URLMonitor also works "fine", but here comes to problem:

When testing the app on the emulator, it can without a problem detect that there is no internet connection. BUT, when exporting to .apk and running on my android device, it won't succeed in detecting the internet connectivity.

Here's my code:

```
var monitor:URLMonitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest("http://www.google.nl"));
monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, netConnectivity);
monitor.start();

function netConnectivity(e:StatusEvent):void 
{
    if(e.target.available)
    {
      //checking the content
      output_txt.text += "\ninternet available";
      loader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(webURL));
      loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOErrorLoader);
      loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteLoader);
    }
    else
    {
      //
      //
      //     NO INTERNET CONNECTION AVAILABLE!
      //
      //
      output_txt.text += "\nno internet available";
      popupnoconnection_mc.alpha = 100;
      popupnoconnection_mc.play();
      popupnoconnection_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, BackToMenu);
    }
    monitor.stop();
}
```

As you can see, it adds an EventListener to the URLMonitor, starts the checking, and the function checks the availability of the internet connection. WORKS ON THE EMULATOR, NOT PROPERLY ON MY DEVICE.

**What's even more interesting:**
What DOES work on my device, is when the internet IS connected. It will just show the text in my output field, but it won't when there is no internet connection!
Also, when lauching the app with an internet connection set up, then entering this frame, then going back to the main menu, then turning the internet off, and then entering this frame again, this code suddently works great!

So it has got to do something with the creation of the URLMonitor, and checking the connection at the same frame I guess, but I need a little hand here!

**I think this can't be too difficult!**

Thank you so much in advance! (sorry for typos)

Comment: The URLMonitor is not that sophisticated. It works by periodically trying to access the URL. It seems conceivable that a mobile device could circumvent this mechanism when it knows there is no connection. Since it relies on an HTTP request to fail, it's possible that no http request is made at all by the device when there is no connection.

Comment: thanks, I'll just trace a "no internet connection?!" to the user if the time trying to access the page is too long. Thank you again for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NetworkInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetworkInfo.html) to detect whether there is an internet connection - it works on Android.